# Kotlin can't use 'this' on init

Tags: kotlin

I want `game` to be set to a new instance of `Game` and I want to pass `this` into game. SO this is what I have.

```
var game: Game

init {
    game = Game(this)
}
```

I have also tried

```
var game: Game = Game(this)
```

both threw a `NullPointer` at run time but it seems fine in Intellij and has no problem compiling. What am I doing wrong?

*Stack Trace*

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:135) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:329) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:251) [server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:292) [server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:198) [server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:525) [server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.registerEvents(SimplePluginManager.java:523) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.gameSettings.GameSettingsManager.addGameSettings(GameSettingsManager.kt:43) ~[?:?]
at me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.gameSettings.GameSettingsManager.<init>(GameSettingsManager.kt:20) ~[?:?]
at me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.Game.<init>(Game.kt:49) ~[?:?]
at me.darkpaladin.uhc.UHC.<init>(UHC.kt:20) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:76) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:131) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
... 6 more
```

*UHC Class*

```
var game: Game

init {
    game = Game(this)
}

override fun onReady() {
    //        new Lobby(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), this, false);
    TeamManager()
    registerCommands()
}

fun registerCommands() {
    val c = commandHandler
    c.addCommand(
            TeamCommand(),
            SetGameTypeCommand(game),
            ClaimHostCommand(game),
            StartGameCommand(game),
            ScenarioManagerCommand(game),
            KillTopCommand(game),
            ConfigCommand(game),
            ScatterCommand(game)
    )
}

fun registerListeners() {
    val p = Bukkit.getPluginManager()
    p.registerEvents(GamePlayerListener(game), this)
}
```

*Game Class*

```
package me.darkpaladin.uhc.game

import me.darkpaladin.core.Core
import me.darkpaladin.core.utils.CoreUtils
import me.darkpaladin.core.utils.PacketUtils
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.UHC
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.events.GameStartEvent
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.events.GameStopEvent
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.gameEvents.GameEvent
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.gameEvents.GameEventRunnable
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.gamePlayers.GamePlayer
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.gamePlayers.GamePlayerManager
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.gameSettings.GameSettingsManager
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.scenarios.ScenarioManager
import org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils
import org.bukkit.*
import org.bukkit.entity.Item
import org.bukkit.entity.Monster
import org.bukkit.entity.Player
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable

import java.util.*

/**
 * Created by Caleb on 4/28/2017.
 */
class Game(private val plugin: UHC) {

    var gameType = GameType.NORMAL
    var gameState = GameState.SETTING_UP
    var gameStartTicks = (CoreUtils.ticksPerSecond * 10).toLong()
    var finalHealTime = (CoreUtils.ticksPerSecond * 15).toLong()
    var pvpTicks = (CoreUtils.ticksPerSecond * 20).toLong()
    var meetupTicks = (CoreUtils.ticksPerSecond * 25).toLong()
    var isBorderShrink = true
    var episodeLength = (CoreUtils.ticksPerMinute * 20).toLong()
    private var episode = 1

    private val worlds = ArrayList<World>()

    private val gameEvents = ArrayList<GameEvent>()

    var gameTicks: Long = 0L

    var hostUuid: UUID? = null

    val scenarioManager: ScenarioManager = ScenarioManager(this)
    val gamePlayerManager: GamePlayerManager = GamePlayerManager()
    val gameSettingsManager: GameSettingsManager = GameSettingsManager(this)

    private val instance: Game

    init {
        worlds.add(Bukkit.getWorld("world")) //TODO: remove
        instance = this
    }

    val overworld: World?
        get() = getWorldWithEnvironment(World.Environment.NORMAL)

    val nether: World?
        get() = getWorldWithEnvironment(World.Environment.NETHER)

    val end: World?
        get() = getWorldWithEnvironment(World.Environment.THE_END)

    fun getWorldWithEnvironment(environment: World.Environment): World? {
        return worlds.firstOrNull { it.environment == environment }
    }

    fun addGameEvent(vararg events: GameEvent) {
        gameEvents.addAll(Arrays.asList(*events))
    }

    val host: Player
        get() = Bukkit.getPlayer(hostUuid)

    fun start() {
        gameState = GameState.STARTING

        val finalHeal = GameEvent("Final Heal", finalHealTime, object : GameEventRunnable(this) {
            override fun run() {
                Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().forEach { player -> player.health = player.maxHealth }
                CoreUtils.broadcast(Core.PREFIX + "Final Heal has been given. This is the FINAL heal. Do not ask for more.")
            }
        })

        val pvp = GameEvent("PvP", pvpTicks, object : GameEventRunnable(this) {
            override fun run() {
                for (world in worlds) {
                    world.pvp = true
                    world.setGameRuleValue("doMobSpawning", "true")
                }
            }
        })

        val starting = GameEvent("Starting in", gameStartTicks, object : GameEventRunnable(this) {
            override fun run() {
                gameTicks = 0L
                addGameEvent(finalHeal, pvp)
                if (isBorderShrink)
                    addGameEvent(BorderShrinkGameEvent(meetupTicks, instance))

                for (player in Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    player.health = player.maxHealth
                    player.foodLevel = 20
                    player.saturation = 20f
                    player.level = 0
                    player.exp = 0f
                    player.totalExperience = 0
                    player.closeInventory()
                    player.inventory.clear()
                    player.inventory.armorContents = null
                    player.gameMode = GameMode.SURVIVAL
                    player.activePotionEffects.forEach { potionEffect -> player.removePotionEffect(potionEffect.type) }
                }

                for (world in worlds) {
                    for (entity in world.entities) {
                        if (entity is Item || entity is Monster) {
                            entity.remove()
                        }
                    }
                    world.pvp = false
                    world.difficulty = Difficulty.HARD
                    world.time = 20
                    world.setSpawnFlags(false, false)
                }

                Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().forEach { player -> gamePlayerManager.addGamePlayers(GamePlayer(player.uniqueId)) }

                val players = ArrayList<Player>()
                gamePlayerManager.aliveGamePlayers
                        .filter { gamePlayer -> gamePlayer.player != null }
                        .forEach { gamePlayer -> players.add(gamePlayer.player) }

                scenarioManager.giveStartingItems(players)

                gameState = GameState.RUNNING
                Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(GameStartEvent(instance))

            }
        })

        addGameEvent(starting)

        GameTimer().runTaskTimer(plugin, 0, 1)
        if (gameType === GameType.RECORDED)
            EpisodeTimerTask()
    }

    val nextEvent: GameEvent?
        get() {
            val events = gameEvents

            val times = HashMap<GameEvent, Long>()

            events.forEach { gameEvent -> times.put(gameEvent, gameEvent.time) }

            var nextEvent: GameEvent? = null
            var nextEventTime: Long = 999999999999999999L
            for (event in times.keys) {
                if (event.time < nextEventTime) {
                    nextEvent = event
                    nextEventTime = event.time
                }
            }
            return nextEvent
        }

    fun getNextBorderRadius(world: World): Int {
        return Math.round(world.worldBorder.size / 2 * .75).toInt()
    }

    private inner class GameTimer : BukkitRunnable() {
        override fun run() {

            val nextEvent = nextEvent

            if (nextEvent != null) {
                if (gameTicks!! % 20 == 0L) {
                    PacketUtils.sendAction(Core.HIGHLIGHTED_COLOR.toString() + ChatColor.BOLD.toString() + WordUtils.capitalizeFully(nextEvent.name) + Core.EXTRA_COLOR + " » " + Core.HIGHLIGHTED_COLOR + CoreUtils.formatTicks(nextEvent.time - gameTicks!!))
                }

                if (gameTicks >= nextEvent.time) {
                    nextEvent.runnable!!.run()
                    gameEvents.remove(nextEvent)
                }
            }

            gameTicks++

        }
    }

    private inner class BorderShrinkGameEvent(time: Long, game: Game) : GameEvent("Border Shrink", time, object : GameEventRunnable(game) {
        override fun run() {
            for (world in worlds) {
                val wb = world.worldBorder

                val radius = Math.round(wb.size / 2).toInt()
                val newRadius = Math.round(wb.size / 2 * .75).toInt()

                if (newRadius < 50)
                    wb.size = 100.0
                else
                    wb.size = (newRadius * 2).toDouble()

                CoreUtils.broadcast(Core.PREFIX + "The border has shrunk from " + radius + " to " + Math.round(wb.size / 2).toInt() + "!")

                if (wb.size > 100) {
                    game.addGameEvent(BorderShrinkGameEvent(CoreUtils.ticksPerSecond * 5 + game.gameTicks!!, game))
                }

            }
        }
    })

    private inner class EpisodeTimerTask : BukkitRunnable() {

        private var ticks: Long = 0

        init {
            ticks = episodeLength
        }

        override fun run() {

            if (ticks <= 0) {
                cancel()

                CoreUtils.broadcast(Core.PREFIX + "End of episode " + episode + ". Start episode " + episode + 1)
                episode++
                return
            }

            ticks--
        }
    }

    fun stop() {
        scenarioManager.disableAll()
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(GameStopEvent(this))

        plugin.game = Game(plugin)
    }

}
```

*Game Setting Manager*

```
package me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.gameSettings

import me.darkpaladin.core.Core
import me.darkpaladin.uhc.game.Game
import org.bukkit.Bukkit
import org.bukkit.event.Listener

import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.stream.Collectors

/**
 * Created by caleb on 5/6/17.
 */
class GameSettingsManager(game: Game) {

    private val gameSettings = ArrayList<GameSetting>()

    init {
        addGameSettings(
                FriendlyFireGameSetting(game),
                NotchApplesGameSetting(),
                DoubleArrowsGameSetting()
        )
    }

    fun getGameSettings(): List<GameSetting> {
        return gameSettings
    }

    val toggleableGameSettings: List<ToggleableGameSetting>
        get() {
            val settings = ArrayList<ToggleableGameSetting>()
            for (setting in getGameSettings())
                if (setting is ToggleableGameSetting)
                    settings.add(setting)
            return settings
        }

    fun addGameSettings(vararg gameSettings: GameSetting) {
        this.gameSettings.addAll(Arrays.asList(*gameSettings))
        for(setting in gameSettings)
            Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(setting as Listener, Core.instance)
    }

    fun getGameSetting(name: String): GameSetting {
        return gameSettings.stream()
                .filter { gameSetting -> gameSetting.name.equals(name, ignoreCase = true) }
                .collect(Collectors.toList<GameSetting>())[0]
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace

Comment: sure can @Graham

Comment: What is the name of your class? Or possibly post it if it isn't too long.

Comment: If the class is called UHC please post that, and post the Game class as well.

Comment: Also the GamesSettingManager please

Comment: @Graham There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 43 of the `GameSettingsManager`:

```
fun addGameSettings(vararg gameSettings: GameSetting) {
    this.gameSettings.addAll(Arrays.asList(*gameSettings))
    for(setting in gameSettings) //line 43 is the one below this
      Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(setting as Listener, Core.instance)
}
```

One of your `setting` objects that is being passed into `Bukkit.getPluginManager()` is `null`.

Or `Core.Instance` is `null`.

One other possibility is that the object being returned by `getPluginManager()` has an unitialized variable inside it that is being referenced in the `registerEvents()` function.

But the most likely case is that one of your `setting` objects is null or `Core.Instance` is null.

**Edit**

https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/plugin/SimplePluginManager.java

Here is the `registerEvents()` function from the `SimplePluginManager` in the bukkit library that gets run:

```
public void registerEvents(Listener listener, Plugin plugin) {
  if (!plugin.isEnabled()) {
    //the next line is 523
    throw new IllegalPluginAccessException("Plugin attempted to register " + listener + " while not enabled");
  }

  for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends Event>, Set<RegisteredListener>> entry : plugin.getPluginLoader().createRegisteredListeners(listener, plugin).entrySet()) {
    getEventListeners(getRegistrationClass(entry.getKey())).registerAll(entry.getValue());
  }

}
```

According to your stack trace line 523 is the one throwing the `null` pointer exception. So something there is `null`. The listener variable is coming from your gameSettings array though.

Looking at your code there really shouldn't be a `null` in that gameSettings `varargs` array. But the function that throws the error is saying otherwise. It would be a good idea to debug to that location or do a `println` as your looping through the gameSettings array to verify that none of it is null.

Comment: `Core.instance` is not null and everything being passed into the add game is in the `init` of `GameSettingsManager` so I don't think any of those are null either. Originally I was registering the Listener of the game settings on the `init` of them but that also threw a `NullPointer`

Comment: Also all of this code worked before when I was just using Java.